# Calculating the final grade from tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
Lloyd = {
    "name":"Lloyd",
    "homework": [90,97,75,92],
    "quizzes": [ 88,40,94],
    "tests": [ 75,90]
    }
Alice = {
    "name":"Alice",
    "homework": [100,92,98,100],
    "quizzes": [82,83,91],
    "tests": [89,97]
    }
Tyler = {
    "name":"Tyler",
    "homework": [0,87,75,22],
    "quizzes": [0,75,78],
    "tests": [100,100]
    }

def average(value):
    avg=0
    items = len(value)
    for item in value:
        avg +=item 
    return avg/items

def getAverage(dictin):
    hw = average(dictin.get('homework'))
    quiz = average(dictin.get('quizzes'))
    tests = average(dictin.get('tests'))
    weighted_average = hw*.1 + quiz*.3 + tests*.6
    return weighted_average

def getLetterGrade(score):
    if score >=90:
        return "A"
    elif score < 90 and score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score < 80 and score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score < 70 and score >= 60:
        return "D"
    elif score < 60:
        return "F"
    else:
        return "No grades for you"

score = getAverage(Lloyd)
grade = getLetterGrade(score)
print grade
```

This works fine but I am told that in the case of the score being 89.5, it would not work.  I tried that as well but I am not able to find out where the problem could be.  Any mistakes are welcome.

Comment: FYI, Python supports readable inequalities: `60 <= score < 70`. Also, how will it not work?

Comment: This is what I have been told "Your function does not work for a value like 89.5".  As I have already mentioned, I have tried hard coding the score in the last second line of the code and it works fine.  I am reaching out if somebody could point me my mistake.

Comment: Well, how should the code behave for fractional scores? Do they have to be rounded to the nearest integer, or always rounded up, or always rounded down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The catch is probably in the `average` function where you divide an integer (`avg`) by another integer (`items`). Since both operands are integers, Python casts the result to an integer as well, thus the `average` function will never return fractional scores.

There are many possible solutions:

1. Cast one of the operands (either `avg` or `items`) to a float before dividing; e.g. `return float(avg)/items`, or `return (avg+0.0)/items`.
2. Let `avg` start from 0.0 instead of 0 - this ensures that `avg` is always a float.
3. Add `from __future__ import division` to the very beginning of your code. This instructs Python to use division in the Python 3.x way and always return a float.

*Update*: also, according to MrGingerbear's comment, you might consider rounding the score up or down in `getLetterGrade`. If you import the `ceil` and `floor` functions from the `math` module, you can say `ceil(score)` to round it up, `floor(score)` to round it down, or `round(score)` to round it to the nearest integer.

Comment: Good answer. Another possible problem: If you are rounding fractional percentages up to a whole percent, you need to do something like ceil(grade) inside getLetterScore. If you do not do so, getLetterScore(grade) where grade is 89.5 will return "B" instead of rounding up to 90 which should return "A"

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility; I steered away from that because the poster did not specify how the code should behave in that case. (For instance, in my school, fractional percentages were rounded to the nearest integer, so 89.5 would become 90 but 89.49 would become 89).

Comment: Right, good call. Simply calling ceil() would most likely not result in the correct answer. You would most likely want to implement a rounding function (this is heavily dependent on the business rules for the program)

Comment: I've extended my answer based on your comments, thanks.

Comment: I added the rounding to the function as per MrGingerbear and it starts working. Thanks..!!!